# How to short url in nginx

Tags: php, nginx

i am trying to rewrite dynamic url to short url with no luck
the url is `http://exmple.com?user=username`

i have tried

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?user=$1;
```

i would like to short it to:

```
http://exmple.com/site/user name
```

so two question:

1. if i short the url to `http://exmple.com/username`
   how can i use other url queries like `http://exmple.com?search=something`
2. how can i do it??:)

i haved searched everywhere for the answer and find nothing so appriciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/(\/index\.php\?user=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ /site/$1
```

Comment: unknown directive RewriteRule

Comment: This is `apache` format, note that the question is tagged as `nginx`

Answer (score 0):

```
location = /index.php {
    rewrite ^ /site/$arg_user;
}
```

Comment: @user3040832, what do you mean, "nothing"?  please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm assuming that when there's `/site` then always what follows is the username then do this

```
location ^~ /site/(.*) {
  try_files /index.php?user=$1&$query_string =404
}
```